# Are there any examples of code using modern authentication to initiate POP3 connections to O365?

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, pop3, exchange-basicauth

I have several critical applications using POP3 to connect to O365 that need to switch from basic to modern authentication by 10/13/2020.  I came based on [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers/) article from MS that indicated answers to questions would be provided in this forum.  I do not see any graph tools   I need to provide my application teams details around how they can update their applications to begin using modern auth for their POP3 connection.  Is there anything MS has provided that would serve as a reference on how this can be accomplished for POP3?